# DI with viewmodel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, viewmodel

I'm learning IoC for the first time but cannot work out how this works with viewmodels and model binding in a standard ASP.NET MVC controller. Let's say I have a basic controller using tightly coupled repository and viewmodel.

```
public class Sample
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var repo = new SampleRepository();
        var model = new SampleViewModel();
        model.SampleItems = repo.Get();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SampleViewModel model) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I want to use DI to loosely couple this controller from it's dependent classes so I inject the repository and viewmodel in via constructor injection

```
public class Sample
{
    private readonly ISampleRepository _sampleRepository;
    private readonly ISampleViewModel _sampleViewModel;

    public Sample(
          ISampleRepository sampleRepository,
          ISampleViewModel sampleViewModel)
    {
        _sampleRepository =  sampleRepository;
        _sampleViewModel =  sampleViewModel;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         _sampleViewModel.SampleItems = _sampleRepository.Get()

         return View(_sampleViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SampleViewModel model) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My problem is, I'm now injecting a viewmodel in via an interface but the HttpPost Action requires a concrete SampleViewModel to do the model binding?

Have I misunderstood how this works? Should I be attempting to loosely couple my viewmodel from the controller or is this just something that needs tight coupling for the model binder to work? I've seen code out there where people use a service layer to return a viewmodel to the controller, and I know you could also write a custom model binder, but this seems like massive overkill for what I want to do here? All I'm after is a way of injecting in a basic viewmodel that can then be used by a view for GET and POST.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Why are you injecting a view model (you inject services, not models)?

Comment: Apologies for the tagging - first post so I'm learning :(

Comment: So are you saying that it is OK to new up a concrete viewmodel in a controller as per my first example? Is that because the viewmodel is tightly coupled to the view anyway? I thought that DI would mean I never manually new up classes? Apologies for the newbie questions but I'm still trying to get my head around IoC!

Comment: Your MVC view models should be mere data containers; they should not reference any services. Simple DTOs can be created in code, there is no use in abstracting their creation from the consumer. Doing so doesn't improve testability, flexibility or maintainability; I would even say that it decreases all these ilities.

Comment: Thank you Steven. My viewmodel IS just a DTO. It only contains fields and collections. Because of this I you're saying I shouldn't inject it into the controller. Instead the controller is OK to new it up manually. That's what fooled me I think. I just assumed I would inject every class in and never use the new keyword again!

Answer (score 8):

A viewmodel doesn't actually *do* anything. It is basically just a DTO that transfers data from your controller to your view. By definition, it cannot have any dependencies. Instead, it is part of the application's *runtime state*.

[Injecting runtime data is anti-pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). Instead, your controller should create an instance of your viewmodel, as it is always expected to return one. There is no reason to mock it for testing, nor is there any reason to replace its implementation. So, there is also no reason to make an abstraction of it (an interface or abstract class).

```
public class Sample
{
    private readonly ISampleRepository _sampleRepository;

    public Sample(
          ISampleRepository sampleRepository)
    {
        _sampleRepository =  sampleRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var sampleViewModel = new SampleViewModel()
        {
            SampleItems = _sampleRepository.Get(),
            // Other initialization here...
        };

        return View(sampleViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SampleViewModel model) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok. My viewmodel IS just a data container. It consists of fields and collections only and it's filled by the controller. As I'm an ioc newbie, the thing that fooled me I think was the controller having a dependency on the viewmodel. I assumed that implementing DI meant I'd never manually new up another class again. I believe what you're telling me is that because the viewmodel is a DTO only and therefore doesn't need testing/mocking, and because the viewmodel is tightly coupled to the view anyway (via the model binding), that I'm fine to new up the concrete viewmodel in my controller?

Comment: @JoshRees Yes, that's correct. Using DI doesn't mean you will never use the new keyword to instantiate objects ever again. Only use DI where it makes sense, just like everything.

Comment: Cheers Martin. Exactly the info I was looking for.